# Easy way to fix spacing in horizontal slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dd4h4uch/), there is an awkward spacing between a slide element and the right arrow element, this spacing actually changes as the browser resizes.

How do I get rid of this spacing and make everything fit together tightly?

Note that I do not want to make the width of the wrapper (whole slider) fixed (I want it to be relative) because I want to see the entire slider even when browser gets smaller. I do, however, want each slide element to have a fixed width.

I have tried adding the following in CSS but this doesn't help.

```
.next-slide, .prev-slide {
    padding-right: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Comment: that is causing due to padding for li and margin-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I didn't misinterpret your expectations, but I believed you were referring to the way that, if you shrink and grow your browser, you will see the final slide appear and disappear based on whether it completely fits in the visible area, and some amount of gray background space is always visible. For that, I did the following:

- Swapped `float: left` on the slides for `display: inline-block`
- To then counter the extra whitespace appearing between them, add `font-size: 0` to the `.tab-container` (font size is set on each `li` so this only removes unwanted whitespace)
- To prevent line breaks, add `white-space: nowrap` to `.tab-container`. (In developer tools, you can see non-fitting elements were moving to the next line)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what my expectations were. If I am not mistaken, you mean I should take out "float: left" and put in "display: inline-block" in .wrapper .tab-container li {} right?

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion Yes. There are a few ways of placing elements side by side, and I tend to find `float` is less useful than `inline-block` in most situations. In this case, it would be because `white-space: nowrap` doesn't work with floats.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected use below

1. Update width of previous and next slide arrows section to 54px

   .next-slide,
   .prev-slide {
     background: black;
     display: block;
     width: 54px;
2. Increase margin right for the tab -container to 53px

   .wrapper .tab-container {
     margin: 0 53px;

3.Tab container li padding right to 24px

```
.wrapper .tab-container li {
  font: normal 14px 'Arial';
  background: lightgrey !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 15px 24px;
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.next-slide,
.prev-slide {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .3s ease-in-out, left .3s ease-in-out, right .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out, left .3s ease-in-out, right .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out, left .3s ease-in-out, right .3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.next-slide{
  right: 0;
}

.wrapper .tab-container {
  margin: 0 53px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  transition: left .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: left .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: left .3s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper .tab-container li {
  font: normal 14px 'Arial';
  background: lightgrey !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.wrapper .tab-container li a {
  background-image: none !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  color: #222;
}

.wrapper .tab-container li a span {
  background-image: none !important;
  /*background-repeat: 0 !important;*/
  background-position: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.wrapper .tab-container li.here,
.wrapper .tab-container li.here a {
  font-weight: normal !important;
  color: #00ac7f !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/dd4h4uch/5/

Comment: I believe this code has browser related fix included, is it so?